# Determinants: periodic entries $0,1,2,3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sequences-and-series, determinants, algebraic-combinatorics

Consider an $n\times n$ matrix $M_n$ where the sequence 
$$\{1,2,3,\dots,n^2\} \mod 4=\{1,2,3,0,1,2,3,\dots\}$$ forms a clock-wise spiral, in that given order. For example,
$$M_4=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3&0\\ 0&1&2&1\\ 3&0&3&2 \\ 2&1&0&3 \end{bmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
M_5=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3&0&1\\ 0&1&2&3&2 \\ 3&0&1&0&3 \\
2&3&2&1&0 \\ 1&0&3&2&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

> **Question.** Is it true that 
>   $$\det(M_{2n})=3(2n-1)4^{n-1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
> \det(M_{2n+1})=-(3n^2-1)4^n\,\,\,?$$

**Added clarification.** To understand the construction of the above matrices, take a look at the matrices [from my other MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270525/smith-normal-form-for-specialized-matrices). Then, reduce the entries modulo $4$ and follow through by computing the determinants.

Comment: Something I noticed when doing some larger versions: each column is the same as the column 4 before, with 2 exceptions, one of which is 2, the other of which is -2. Other than the first four columns, and switching the signs of some columns, you get 2s and -2s in two diagonals.

Comment: By quotient matrix, we can compute the determinants of the above examples simply. Maybe, by some good partitioning of your matrices, we can prove your claim.

Comment: I would be happy to see your claim verified.

Comment: Seems like $M_n$ is the central submatrix of $M_{n+2}$. I don't know how to use this though.

Comment: If $C_1,\ldots,C_{2n}$ denote the columns of $M_{2n}$ then $C_i \equiv C_{i+2} \pmod{2}$. Replacing $C_{2i+1}$ by $C_{2i+1}-C_1$ and $C_{2i+2}$ by $C_{2i+2}-C_2$ for any $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ yields a matrix where $2n-2$ columns consist of even entries, hence the determinant is divisible by $4^{n-1}$. Probably a similar argument can show that the determinant is divisible by 3.

Comment: This is an interest start.

Comment: Adding the first and last rows (resp. columns) in $M_{2n}$ if $n \equiv 0$ resp. $1 \pmod{2}$ shows that $\det M_{2n}$ is divisible by 3.

Comment: Extending my above observation: if you do both that column manipulation and the corresponding row manipulation, you are left with an almost 4-antidiagonal matrix (where the 4 antidiagonals are 1 below, 3 below, 5 below, and 7 below the "true" antidiagonal). Those antidiagonals are filled with 2 and -2, in a predictable way. The only exception is the 4 by 4 matrix in the top left corner, which is $M_{2n}$.

Comment: The observation that $M_n$ is the central submatrix of $M_{n+2}$ makes me wonder if [Dodgson condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation) could be relevant. But these matrices have lots of zeros.

Comment: An observation about the matrix $M_n$ (easy to prove by induction): It has the property that $\left(M_n\right)_{i,j} \equiv \left(M_n\right)_{i+1,j-1} + 2 \mod 4$ for all $i \leq n-1$ and $j \geq 2$. Thus, its values can be easily computed without completing the spiral.

Comment: Here is a sort-of-explicit formula for each entry of $M_n$: We have $\left(M_n\right)_{i,j} \equiv 1+i+j + 2 \begin{cases} i-1, & \text{if } i+j-1 \leq n; \\ n-j, & \text{if } i+j-1 \geq n \end{cases} \mod 4$.

Comment: Equivalently, $\left(M_n\right)_{i,j} \equiv j-i+1 + 2q\left(n-i-j+1\right) \mod 4$, where $q \left(m\right) = \left[m < 0\right] m$ for each integer $m$ (where we are using the Iverson bracket notation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is true. More generally, the entries $1,2,3,0$ can be replaced by arbitrary numbers $a,b,c,d$, in which case the determinant of $M_n$ can be computed in terms of the four numbers $u = d-b$, $v = a-c$, $U = d+b$ and $V = a+c$ as follows:

- If $n=4k$ for some positive integer $k$, then
  $$
  \det\left(  M_{n}  \right)  =\dfrac{1}{4}
  v^{n-4}\left(  v^{4}-u^{2}v^{2}+\left(  U^{2}-V^{2}\right)  \left(  \left(
  2k-1\right)  ^{2}v^{2}-\left(  2k\right)  ^{2}u^{2}\right)  \right)  .
  $$
- If $n=4k+2$ for some positive integer $k$, then
  $$
  \det\left(  M_{n} \right)  =-\dfrac{1}{4}%
  v^{n-4}\left(  v^{4}-u^{2}v^{2}+\left(  U^{2}-V^{2}\right)  \left(  \left(
  2k+1\right)  ^{2}v^{2}-\left(  2k\right)  ^{2}u^{2}\right)  \right)  .
  $$
- If $n=4k+1$ for some positive integer $k$, then
  $$
  \det\left(  M_{n}  \right)  =\dfrac{1}{2}
  u^{n-3}\left(  u^{2}\left(  v+V\right)  -\left(  2k\right)  ^{2}v\left(
  U^{2}-V^{2}\right)  \right)  .
  $$
- If $n=4k+3$ for some positive integer $k$, then
  $$
  \det\left(  M_{n}  \right)  =\dfrac{1}{2}
  vu^{n-3}\left(  u^{2}+vV-\left(  2k+1\right)  ^{2}\left(  U^{2}-V^{2}\right)
  \right)  .
  $$

As you can imagine, this is not very fun to prove. I have a writeup ([*The 4-periodic spiral determinant*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/spiral4det.pdf)) in which I attempt at making the idea clear without going into all the details; in particular, annoying computations are relegated to [SageMath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) and to the reader (and on some occasions to a combination of both). Even at that level of terseness, it is 24 pages long. I would normally hope that something nicer can be found, but with the complexity of the answer I am not too hopeful.

The proof starts out as suggested by @user44191 in one of the comments to the original post; thus the matrix is brought to a form where all entries are zero except for those in northwesternmost $4\times 4$-submatrix and on four sub-antidiagonals (namely, the $1$-st, the $3$-rd, the $5$-th and the $7$-th sub-antidiagonals) below the main antidiagonal. Then, I turn the matrix upside down, so that the sub-antidiagonals become the super-diagonals. I then perform Laplace expansion with respect to the last $4$ rows. All $4 \times 4$-minors from the last $4$ rows can be explicitly computed (only $\dbinom{7}{4}$ of them nonzero, and this can be further reduced by looking at the vanishing of the complementary minors), so it remains to compute the complementary $\left(n-4\right)\times\left(n-4\right)$-minors. For this, [Jacobi's complementary minor theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87877/jacobis-equality-between-complementary-minors-of-inverse-matrices) turns out to be of use, along with an explicit computation of the inverse of a certain power series.